# IE9 receives JSON response as a line of CharCodes in Restangular

Tags: json, angularjs, internet-explorer-9, restangular, angular-http

In my application we use Restangular and $http to communicate with server API.

First request (the one /BasicInfo.json on the picture) is done using Restangular for retrieving initial information, like user name, and also Number pointer to part of the of the app is used (**appId**). 
Other requests use this data for further calls, they are done just with using regular $http service.

But in IE9 specifically (not >=IE10, I also have html5shiv) I get the resolved response as a string of chars, like this:

```
[123,23,45,98,143,...]
```

That is why first piece of data is not processed properly and other calls cannot resolve - see "undefined" in the URL in the picture. Second and subsequent call use following patters for forming the URL.

```
//baseURL and docId - are available, while appId is not
$http.get(baseURL + '/api/' + appId + '/Subjects/' + docId + '.json')
.success(function(data){ deferred.resolve(data);
..
```

[image: requests in the app]

This line is actually a list of Chars containing correct server response, but in such a weird way. I've found the way to convert it using function like this:

```
//numbersLine is that actual line [123,23,45,98,143,...] 
  var str = '',
  convertedArray = Array(numbersLine)[0];

for (var i = 0; i < convertedArray.length; i++) {
    str = str + String.fromCharCode(convertedArray[i]);
}

return str;
```

But I have to do this conversion everywhere in the app where I deal with API data, because of this IE9 strange behaviour.
Any advice about what I could check/change would be very appreciated.

**[UPD]**

This is module setup

```
define([
    'angular',
    './modulename',
    'app/base/base-module',
//module definition via RequireJS

angular.module('app.modulename').config(
        ['$stateProvider', '$BasicProvider', 
            function ($stateProvider, $BasicProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('***', {
                    url: '***',
                    views : {
                        ///
                    },
                    resolve : {
                        //here should get POJO with appid
                        resolvedBasicInfo : ["$Basic", function($Basic){
                            return $Basic.getBasicInfo();
                        }],
//later goest two other calls that require this appid
```

And Base module itself has Restangular call

```
define([
    'angular',
    'restangular',
    //other configs

], function( angular, Restangular ) {

    'use strict';

    return angular.module('effactsApp.base').provider('$Basic', function(){

        return {
            $get : ['Restangular', 'baseApiService', //other configs
                function (Restangular, baseApiService) {
//

                    if(!basicInfoRestCall){
                        basicInfoRestCall = Restangular.one('BasicInfo');
                    }
```

@dhavalcengg, hope it gives the idea

Comment: Can you post some code, when your are setting appid for your application? Also response you are getting when sending request for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the header for the response in the $http header to 
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8?

[documentation for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Comment: $http is done via Restangular and $http services; setup is correct since it works in *all* other browsers, IE11 and IE10 as well

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally I've found the issue that directly happened in my case: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5429

This is exactly conditions I had:

- PDF.js + compatibility.js
- AngularJS + Router + AJAX calls
- IE9

Which leaded to XHR request to load data in incorrect way.